# Attach multiple files to Outlook email from a filtered list and loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of customers with their invoice data (one customer may have one or more than one rows of data). I have assembled a macro script from multiple codes to filter out the customer (basis on email address) and send them a dunning letter with their account statement.

The code is working fine with email creation, except I am not able to attach their invoice copies listed in column 2 (In TempoWB workbook).

I think the problem is with `Loop` The code is jumping from `Do while` directly to `.HTMLBody`.It's skipping the previous codes to search and attach files. How can I fix it?

Here is the [Zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1npCaGoO2LvQjQYd0ahGreAcRP-WsP5tX/view?usp=sharing) with all required data and files. In case you want to give it a try. Just copy the 'Renamed' invoice folder to C:\Invoices.

(customer names and other data has been altered for compliance reason)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Dunning_3_Populate_Emails_TempWB()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'This code populates emails to outlook as per the Credit analysts.

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim Ash As Worksheet
        Dim Cws As Worksheet
        Dim Rcount As Long
        Dim Rnum As Long
        Dim name_rg As Range
        Dim name As String
        Dim Subj As String
        Dim irow As Integer
        Dim dpath As String
        Dim pfile As String
        Dim strbody As String
        Dim TempoWB As Workbook

     'Folder location for Invoice copies

        dpath = "C:\Invoices\Renamed"

     'Column number to pick the invoices
        irow = 2

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

         name = Ash.Cells(name_rg.Row, 16)
         Subj = Ash.Cells(name_rg.Row, 15)
        Else
         name = "email not found in Ash"
        End If
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'This portion has codes to filter the required data based on the unique email address

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


     'Create a new workbook with selected/ filtered data
        rng.Copy
        Set TempoWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
        With TempoWB.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
             On Error Resume Next
            .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            .DrawingObjects.Delete
             Columns("O:Q").Select
             Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
             On Error GoTo 0

     'Location to save the temporary workbook
             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             TempoWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Invoices\TempoWB.xlsx"
        End With


     'E-mail body for the dunning letters

        strbody = "Hello " & name & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _

                  "<b>Below is the summary of your account and attached are the invoices:</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>"


        On Error GoTo Cleanup

        On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
        .Subject = subj

         Workbooks("TempoWB.xlsx").Activate
For irow = 2 To Lastrow

        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Dunning Temp\" & Cells(irow, 2).Value & ".pdf")

Next

        .HTMLBody = strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & .HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If

 'Close TempoWB
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks("TempoWB.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error Resume Next

 'Close AutoFilter
    Ash.AutoFilterMode = False


    Next Rnum

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Re: Is Excel....? That is a link for you to follow. They are not the same at all. Please remove the vb.net tag.

Comment: @Mary Thanks! I've removed that.

Comment: (This is too much code to present for a Stack Overflow problem. Are you able to cut this down to a [mcve]?)

Comment: @halfer I have summarized the code which is only needed to be fixed

Comment: OK, that's better. However it isn't clear what you are stuck on, other than "I am not able to attach their invoice copies". Why not? I guess the issue is `.Attachments.Add` - does this return an error? Is there a return value from this that designates success/failure?

Comment: @halfer I think the problem is with the `Loop` The code is jumping from `Do while` directly to `.HTMLBody` .It's skipping the previous codes to search and attach files. I couldn't figure out the fix. If it runs through all the lines, it would add the files.

Comment: @halfer Could you please remove the hold from my question now?

Comment: @PrateekVishwas: I think it is probably still a no from me (I cannot personally remove the hold, I can only cast one vote to do so). There's a couple of things you need to know about this site. Firstly, ProfoundlyOblivious appears to have undertaken a substantial piece of free work for you, which is _not_ the purpose of Stack Overflow. If he has been unable to solve it despite 23 comments back-and-forth, then it could be suggested that the question about is/was not sufficiently clear as to be fixable.

Comment: It sounds like in this question you are saying the `While` loop is not getting called. However, it seems that under the current answer, you made some progress, but that is not reflected in the question. Is the code in the question, and the state of the problem in the question, the very latest you have on this bug?

Comment: @halfer You are correct! The `While` loop is working for only first TempoWB.xlsx created by the code. for the rest of the workbooks It's not attaching any file with the email. While debugging I noticed that the code is jumping from `Do While TempoWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty` to `.HTMLBody = strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & Signature`. It's skipping the code lines between both these lines for rest of the temporary workbooks i.e. TempoWb.xlsx

Comment: OK, so debug that. What is the value of `irow` when it fails to run the inner `While`? Do you need to reset this to the initial value inside the outer loop?

Comment: @halfer value for `irow` is 2. i.e. the code will pick up the string from the second row of TempoWB.xlsx. While debugging I moved the cursor manually to the next line of `Do While.....` (when it skipped these lines and jumped to last `.HTML....` line). But strangely it's picking up the value from the Main workbook instead of TempoWB.xlsx. I tried workbook activate method as well but it didn't work. Sorry for so much trouble in understanding. I am a beginner in vb macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial suspicion of the row counter was just flat wrong. The problem turned out to be several small errors that simply caused the code to look for the attachment in places it could never find it.

Two things you should know:

1) The code currently in your question didn't feel right so I tossed it and went with the version you originally posted.

2) You need to update the path/directory strings and clear some comment blocks I've made.  Nothing too difficult.

```
    Option Explicit                                                     'PO - Option Explicit, use it !

Sub Dunning_3_Populate_Emails()


 Dim test1 As Long, test2 As Long
 test1 = Timer
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'This code populates emails to outlook.

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim name_rg As Range
    Dim name As String
    Dim Subj As String
    Dim irow As Integer
    Dim dpath As String
    Dim pfile As String
    Dim strbody As String


    dpath = Environ("appdata") & "\VBA\Stack Overflow\Attachments"      'PO - my environment only, delete
    '    dpath = "C:\Invoices\Renamed"                                  'PO - original code, use if it is correct or modify


    irow = 2

    'looping through all the files and sending an mail

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    'C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures           'PO - not my edit, guessing it is here for reference


'----------------------------------------------------------------
'PO - blocked this off because it wasn't related to the problem
'     should be perfectly ok to unblock
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
'                "\Microsoft\Signatures\My Signature.htm"
'
'    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
'       Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
'    Else
'        Signature = ""
'    End If
'
'    On Error Resume Next
'
'    With Application
'        .EnableEvents = False
'        .ScreenUpdating = False
'    End With
'----------------------------------------------------------------


    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = ActiveSheet

    'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:Q" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 17    'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
            CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
            If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' ~ Search email address from Cws into Ash ~
    Set name_rg = Ash.Columns(17).Find(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1))

    If Not name_rg Is Nothing Then

     name = Ash.Cells(name_rg.Row, 16)

     Subj = Ash.Cells(name_rg.Row, 15)

    Else
     name = "email not found in Ash"
    End If


    Set name_rg = Nothing

    strbody = "Hello " & name & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "Hope you are fine!" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "I am writing to share the list of open invoice(s) on your account with <b>Keysight Technologies Inc.</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "Please refer to th account statement below and let me know if you show any discrepancy on any of the open invoice(s), so that the required help can be arranged asap to get that resolved." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "Also, if the invoice(s) has been paid already, kindly share the payment details" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "<mark><i>** Please let me know if you have not recieved invoice copy so that I can arrange the invoice copy for you.</i></mark>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
              "<b>Below is the summary of your account:</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>"


    On Error GoTo Cleanup


    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
        .Subject = Subj

'----------------------------------------------------------------
'PO - ranges and objects should be qualified to avoid bugs
'     It is very likely Cells() was reading from the last active sheet (Cws)
'----------------------------------------------------------------

        'Do While Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty                         'PO - unqualified, dangerous
         Do While Ash.Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty

             'pikcing up file name from column B
             'pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 2) & "*")     'PO - unqualified, dangerous
             pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Ash.Cells(irow, 2) & "*")
             'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

             'If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 2) = "pdf" Then      'PO - a 2 letter string cannot equal a 3 letter string
             If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 2) = "xt" Then        'PO - be sure to modify this
            .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
             End If

             'go to next file listed on the C column
             irow = irow + 1

         Loop

        .HTMLBody = strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & Signature
        .Send
    End With


'   Set ws = Nothing                                                'PO - "ws" is undefied, probably "Cws"

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
            'Close AutoFilter
            Ash.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next Rnum
    End If


Cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Cws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    test2 = Timer
    MsgBox "All the Collection Letters have been sent and it took only " & Format((test2 - test1) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss") & " Seconds."

End Sub
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

'    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"           'PO forward slash is wrong syntax
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        Columns("O:Q").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

And lastly, the nested while loops are the reason you started getting stuck in a loop.  Reducing your code to illustrate the point, it looked something ike this:

```
Do While Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty
   Do While Cells(irow, 2) = Empty
   Loop
Loop
```

Both conditions will almost always be met so you get stuck on the inside loop if the cell is empty and you get stuck on the outside loop if the cell is populated.

Comment: It's not working and the excel is getting stuck everytime (only 10-15 rows) I run the script with your code. Maybe I pasted it at the wrong place. Could you please let me know where to put your loop or show in my original code above?

Comment: I have edited the code and It's still not attaching the invoices to the emails. Could you please check and advice?

Comment: You can replace the line "irow = irow+1" with my code and it could potentially fix a problem with attaching more than one file.  If the problem is that it doesn't attach any files then my code won't help. I noticed your question said the directory of file names was in the second column and your code supports this.  However your documentation suggested column C.  Probably just an oversight but maybe the documentation is right. I will run your code to try finding a better answer.

Comment: You are correct! Column C instead of B was an oversight. I've corrected it. I have replaced the code as you've suggested however, it's still not attaching files. Not sure what I am missing here. Please let me know if this can be corrected. I am glad that you are still concerned about my question. Thank you.

Comment: Simple debugging steps you can take:.  Comment out (put an apostrophe in front) everywhere you see "on  error resume next*   use the search function to make sure you don't miss any.  Run your code and tell me what error you get and where.  When done you can remove the apostraphes..  Put break points behind branches, loops, and at your exit point then  run your code again.  Let me know if the program skips areas it shouldn't or if it exits early, and while in the last break point tell me the final values of your indexing variables (or if you notice a variable wan't populating)

Comment: Hoping to get some time in the next day or two that I can devote to building your project

Comment: I have been debugging from past week and trying to find the error however I am not getting any error. It's just skipping the attachment part. I added breakpoints to all the lines however it's stopping only at the first and second breakpoints then jumping forward to the last breakpoint and saving the email in the outbox. Then it goes to the second email. here is the [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IfvDsDiQqeQvi3E24DFx9_VNqs7Bs7VC/view?usp=sharing). I am not expert in Vb debugging and coding so could not do better. Is it running fine on your system?

Comment: I tried again and now it's getting stuck forever in the loop you've created.

Comment: Hello again! Sorry to bother you again for this, but I couldn't fix the problem. Have you tried?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the wait.  Didn't get a chance to try running the code until today.  First, the good news: I identified and corrected the cause of the missing attachments.  Now the bad news: my hunch was wrong and it had nothing to do with irow.  I'll explain in the answer.

Comment: Great to see your response. I was awaiting your analysis. Mine failed :(

Comment: I have tried your edits however, it's still not working and getting error as in this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C6ZZhN7kfNBi7NV1e_Ly3w3VakTNuZs2). I have attached my macro file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZNWiT1VL0LOxxuc0lJ_YS1CiGGOIuixy). Not sure what am I doing wrong this time.

Comment: Can you pull out the VBA and paste it separately?  It's not that I don't trust you.  I don't trust anyone. Wish I had an answer for you right now.   I can't see enough of what's going on to be sure but it looks like an easy fix.  You might wannat try restting yoru data  s trying to set a filter that can't be set.  Looks like it matches my code roder for word 0 but I don't get that error.screen shot matches exactly to my screen.

Comment: The problem is with this line. `FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value` Earlier this code was not creating any issues. It's showing error Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: I was able to replicate the error - and we'll know very quickly if this works for you.  In my code above, there's a line that says              

'   Set ws = Nothing                       'PO - "ws" is undefied, probably "Cws"                         Now, I'm hoping you changed the line so that it reads     Set Cws = Nothing          If you did that, this will be one of the easiest fixes you've ever done.  Delete the line, or put an apostraphe in front of it, or move it under under "Cleanup:"   That should fix the problem.

Comment: You are right "ws" was the culprit. I've deleted that line and the macro is running now. But again the problem is still there. It's attaching all the invoices from the list with the FIRST EMAIL. Rest emails are without attachments. The only invoices should be attached related to that particular customer. It should pick up file names from visible only data from the filtered list everytime.

Comment: That's amusing.  I seem to recall a different problem with it not sending more than one attachment, and it wouldn't runn at all for me because I use option explicit and squashed all the on error resume next lines. Those problems are definitely fixed. 
Maybe I fixed the wrong problem because I like you so much 
:)   No big deal. Fixing is easy now that it runs.  I'll try look at it again tonight..

Comment: Thank you Sir for not giving up on it :). I am sorry I've been a great headache for you. I am also trying my best but couldn't do much as i am just a beginner and still learning the basics. Googled a lot and still trying to fix the attachment problem. Hope you can do the magic. 

Comment: Hey Prateek,  If the same email address is repeated on the list 10 times.  Does that address get ten emails with 1 attachment or does it get one email with 10 attachments?  I can go either way pretty easily so I think you'll have a working program this weekend but I want to make sure it works the way you expect it to.

Comment: The same email is not getting repeated. The emails are being drafted perfectly with the different email address. It's just the attachments which are getting attached only to the first email drafted by the program. All of the invoice copies in invoice folder is getting attached to the first email.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. It saves a TempoWB (temporary workbook in ":C\invoices") and then uses invoice column from this workwook instead of master workbook. It is able to draft first email attaching correct invoices (only the relevant invoices from the invoice directory). But the rest of the emails are skipping the attachments. While debugging I noticed that the code is jumping from ``Do While TempoWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty`` to ``.HTMLBody = strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & Signature``. Could you fix it to loop through the column B?

Comment: I'll take a look at what you did.  I'd hoped to finish today so if it's too big of a change I may stick with the original plan.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have shared a video link of the running code and final result at my system. Click to see this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11-ev2iri4lcyyjai3V4lrmYRO-Wl0jwc/view?usp=sharing). Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Everyone, after googling a lot i've got a workaround with For Next loop. I've edited my original code with the fix. Thank you @ProfoundlyOblivious. Your ideas helped a lot.